# Pyinstaller-compiled exe can't find file with absolute path

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, exe, pyinstaller

I compiled my Python GUI with Pyinstaller on Windows 10 but it seems like it cannot find my other script even though I provided the hard-coded absolute path to it (with r'"C:\Program Files...script path..."'). I even tried os.isfile (script path) but it returns False. The python script was compiled with `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=iconimage.ico myscript.py` from the command prompt. I use this same command on Ubuntu and the binary works just fine. I read something about Pyinstaller creating a temporary directory which I found, but I don't think it matters where it's running from as long as I give it the full path, so I'm thinking maybe I need more options when compiling? The GUI opens just fine. It's when it needs to call the script that it doesn't do anything. There are no errors when I run it from the command prompt. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `--onedir` which will put everything needed to run the program in one directory in the dist folder.